# Select enum type based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums, refactoring

I have a class:

```
template <class type>
class sysbase : public base
{
 public:
  static type* Spawn(int Config = 0) { … }
  … 
};
```

And about 50 enums in the global namespace:

```
enum a_config { A1, A2, … };
enum b_config { B1, B2, … };
etc.
```

Classes `a`, `b`, etc. (derived from `sysbase`) will be passed as the `type` template argument to `sysbase`.

Now I would like to change the `Config` parameter to be of one of those enum types instead of just a plain int to improve type safety, so that:

- when `type` is class `a`, then the type of `Config` would be `a_config`
- when `type` is class `b`, then the type of `Config` would be `b_config`
- etc.

The enums should preferably stay in the global namespace to not break the existing code which uses e.g. `a::Spawn(A1)`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: To me that sounds like bad design. But you can have a identifier for the class which you look up at initialization and select either a_config or b_config.

Comment: **1) Intrusive solution**: define typedefs of enum-types in the classes as member, and access it as `Spawn(typename type::enum_type config)`. **2) Non-intrusive solution**: define  type-traits that map type to enum and use it as `Spawn(typename enum_type<type>::type config)`. Choose whatever solution suits your situation.

Comment: @Nawaz I get your first example and it seems like a legitimate solution, but could you maybe provide an example on how to implement your second solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Intrusive solution**:  define typedefs of enum-types in the classes as member, and access it as `typename type::enum_type`:

  ```
  class a
  {
     public:
         using enum_type = a_config; //C++11 style typedef
  };

  //define all such classes in the same way.

  //lets also define a friendly template alias to access the enum type.
  template<typename T>
  using enum_type = typename T::enum_type;

  //then you could define Spawn as
  static type* Spawn(enum_type<T> config) { … }
  ```
- **Non-intrusive solution**: define type-traits that map type to enum and use it as `typename enum_type_<type>::type`.

  ```
   template<typename>
   struct enum_type_;  //primary template (no definition)

   //specialize enum_type_ for each class type as:
   template<> 
   struct enum_type_<a>
   { 
      using type = a_config; 
   };

   //now define the alias as
   template<typename T>
   using enum_type = typename enum_type_<T>::type;

  //then you could define Spawn as
  static type* Spawn(enum_type<T> config) { … }
  ```

Well, your `Spawn` function *looks* same in the both cases *because* of carefully chosen alias-name, even though these two solutions are very different from conceptual point of view — one *requires* to edit the class definitions, and the other solves the problem *without* requiring you to edit the classes.

Pick whatever solution suits your situation.

Hope that helps.